# useContext returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am using react-context to create and use contexts. I am unable to use the contexts in the children components of the context-provider.

I can access the contexts on the App context. But whenever I tried to access to separate components the useContext returns undefined.

My App component looks like this.

```
<div className="App">
    <Navbar />
    <Header/>
<InstructorContextProvider>
<InstructorPage />
</InstructorContextProvider>
</div>
```

The instructorContext looks like :

```
const InstructorContextProvider = (props) => {
const [instructorList] = useState([1,2,3,4]); 
return (
   <InstructorContext.Provider value = {[...instructorList]}>
       {props.children}
   </InstructorContext.Provider>
```

The InstructorPage component returns undefined when the InstructorContext is used.

```
const InstructorPage = () => {
const [...instructorList] = useContext(InstructorContext);
console.log(instructorList);
return <h1> hello world </h1>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `[...instructorList]`, just use it like `instructorList`.

And also, if you look at [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-bash-rw1qz)  everything is working fine.

Comment: @user10822859 are you sure you aren't missing something? How you create `InstructorContext` ? In the sandbox, it's working fine

Comment: Thing is I can access the context from some children components but not all.

Comment: Ahh.. Solved it. It was a simple yet silly mistake on my part. It was a named export and I did not import it like a named one. Arghh

Comment: @user10822859 some times it happens